# C++ function call with many dot operator

Tags: c++

It's the first time I came across the following C++ programming pattern. Does this mean that the first return value from `semifuture_signal` is used to trigger `via` followed by `thenValue`. etc. I want to understand this code snippet first then look at some examples of this programming pattern.

```
client->semifuture_signal(signalRequest)
      .via(&executor_)
      .thenValue(xxx)
      .thenError(
          xxx);

return futureResponseMessage;
```

Here are the definitions.

```
virtual folly::SemiFuture< SignalResponse> semifuture_signal(const  ::SignalRequest& request);

Future<T> SemiFuture<T>::via(Executor::KeepAlive<> executor) && {...}

}

Future<T>::thenError(tag_t<ExceptionType>, F&& func) && {...}
```

Comment: The dot (.) operator is used for direct member selection via object name. In other words, it is used to access the child object. It's quite ugly, Facebook is trying to be Javascript.

Comment: @kiranBiradar: Why horrible? because it is not "procedural" but more "functional" ? Do you prefer `thenError(ThenValue, via(client->semifuture_signal(signalRequest), &executor), xxx), xxx);` when you cannot read function from left to right, but have to do inner from outer?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is what you think.

- `via()` is called on the `folly::SemiFuture< SignalResponse>` object that `semifuture_signal()` returns
- then `thenValue()` is called on the `Future<T>` object that `via()` returns
- finally `thenError()` is called on the `Future<T>` object that `thenValue()` returns.

Comment: How do they do that, could you please provide an example for me. I know it is not my question. But could you show an example for a function with the dot operator, and have a onerror()? I do not understand how the return values can pass through each of them.

Comment: @Raymond it is no different than explicitly saving the returned objects to variables and then calling methods on those variables. In this case, the variables are temporary and managed implicitly by the compiler